# How to get only specified item of list?

Tags: mysql, linq, list, asp.net-core

I extract the following data from database with the following MySql Query:

```
SELECT vs.value, vs.is_header, vsa.is_required, vsa.name, vsar.value
FROM vista_struttura AS vs
LEFT JOIN vista_struttura_attributi AS vsa
    ON vs.id_vista_struttura = vsa.id_vista_struttura
LEFT JOIN vista_struttura_attributi_raccordi AS vsar
    ON vsa.input_type = vsar.input_type
ORDER BY vs.sort;
```

Data extracted are

[image]

I have to save this data in a model built from myself with the following code:

```
var model = new List<Header>();
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();                                  
    var sql =   "SELECT vs.value, vs.is_header, vsa.is_required, vsa.name, vsar.value " +
                "FROM vista_struttura AS vs " +
                "LEFT JOIN vista_struttura_attributi AS vsa " +
                    "ON vs.id_vista_struttura = vsa.id_vista_struttura " +
                "LEFT JOIN vista_struttura_attributi_raccordi AS vsar " +
                    "ON vsa.input_type = vsar.input_type " +
                "ORDER BY vs.sort";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

    var rows = new List<ViewProperties>();  

    while (rdr.Read())
    {         
        var value = rdr[0].ToString();
        var isHeader = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr[1]);
        var isRequired = (rdr[2] == DBNull.Value) ? (bool?) null : Convert.ToBoolean(rdr[2]);
        var name = rdr[3].ToString();
        var inputType = rdr[4].ToString();

        var properties = new ViewProperties()
        {
            Value = value,
            IsHeader = isHeader,
            IsRequired = isRequired,
            Name = name,
            InputType = inputType
        };     

        rows.Add(properties); 

        var header = new Header()
        {            
            HeaderValue = (properties.IsHeader == true) ? properties.Value : null,
            Rows = rows
        };
        if (header.HeaderValue != null)
        {
            model.Add(header);
        }

    }                
}
```

**Models**

Header

```
public class Header
{
    public string HeaderValue { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewProperties> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

ViewProperties

```
public class ViewProperties
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsHeader { get; set; }
    public bool? IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InputType { get; set; }
}
```

Debugging the app I get a wrong model, not such as I want...

[image]

I want to get first 4 rows for first header and the other last 3 rows for the second header.

How can i do?

What's better to do: before get this model and then handle it with linq, or get already correct model?

Thanks

Comment: Use GroupBy on `List<ViewProperties>` to achieve the desired result

Comment: Code above has an issue that its adding all the properties to the HeaderValue, there's no discretion or grouping based on header value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following code for the desired result, make the necessary modifications:

```
var rows = new List<ViewProperties>();  // ViewProperties List

// Segregate null value, GroupBy to aggregate using Value
var viewPropertiesGrouping = rows.Where(x => x.IsHeader)
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.Value);

// Traverse through IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,ViewProperties>>, created above and fill the Header object and add to the Model

foreach (var prop in viewPropertiesGrouping)
{
    Header header  = new Header();
    header.HeaderValue = prop.Key;
    header.Rows = prop.Select(y => y).ToList();
    model.Add(header);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I resolved adding a new property _IdGroup_ in model and then grouping result based on IdGroup.

Comment: Glad it helped, in the original code, you have to first create a `List<ViewProperties>` inside the while loop, then the remaining operation including grouping, creating header and adding to the model shall happen outside it. In original code you have put everything inside it while loop, which is major reason for the error